# Saving textfield for each item in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

It seems I have had a lot of questions today.

What i want to do is save the text for each image.
I'm getting the right text for each picture into the textboxes at the moment.

The code behind:

```
var car = GarageBLL.LoadCar(Convert.ToInt32(CarId),
Convert.ToInt32(_memberId)); ImageRepeater.DataSource = car.Images;
ImageRepeater.DataBind();

protected void FinalizeNewCar(object sender, EventArgs e) {
Response.Redirect("/amcargarasjen"); }
**Code here for saving each edit into the right ImageId.**
```

ASP:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="ImageRepeater">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <table>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <a class="deleteLink" href="#" rel="<%#Eval("ImageId")%>" title="">
                   <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="/Content/Images/Garage/DeleteButton.png" /></a>
                   <asp:Image Width="60" Height="45" ID="ImgCar" ImageUrl='<%# String.Format("/garageimages/{0}/{1}.{2}", CarId, Eval("ImageId"), Eval("Extension")) %>' runat="server" />
                   <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' ID="txtText"></asp:TextBox>
               </td>
           </tr>
       </table>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Fullfør" OnClick="FinalizeNewCar" />
```

Anyone got any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your Repeater HTML markup like below. Note the addition of a Hidden field to keep the reference of the current image ID.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="ImageRepeater">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <table>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <a class="deleteLink" href="#" rel="<%#Eval("ImageId")%>" title="">
                   <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="/Content/Images/Garage/DeleteButton.png" /></a>
                   <asp:Image Width="60" Height="45" ID="ImgCar" ImageUrl='<%# String.Format("/garageimages/{0}/{1}.{2}", CarId, Eval("ImageId"), Eval("Extension")) %>' runat="server" />
                   <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' ID="txtText"></asp:TextBox>
                   <asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ImageId") %>' ID="txtImageId"></asp:TextBox> 
               </td>
           </tr>
       </table>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Fullfør" OnClick="FinalizeNewCar" />
```

**CODE FinalizeNewCar Event Handler**

```
protected void FinalizeNewCar(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in ImageRepeater.Items)
    {
        Int32 imageId = Convert.ToInt32(((HiddenField) item.FindControl("txtImageId")).Value);
        string description = ((TextBox)item.FindControl("txtText")).Text;
        //You will get the imageId description here. 
        //Write your code to update the datatbase.
    }
}
```